# failed to mount canonical-livepatch after timeshift

Tags: canonical-livepatch, timeshift

I have backed up my system using Timeshift and removed Ubuntu from my laptop. Then I reinstalled Ubuntu and trying to restore the state using Timeshift snapshot from a recovery hard disk. After recovery is completed the system is not booting up giving an failed error.

[image]